# Subscripted dimension mismatch

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to implement a 2x2 MIMO system no equalization, and I have been getting the error "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch". Here is my matlab code:

```
clc; clear; close all;
N = 100;
Eb_No_dB = (-1 : 20);
n_Tx = 2;
n_Rx = 2;

for kk = 1:N
    for ii = 1 : length(Eb_No_dB)

        % Transmitter
        s = rand(2, 1)>0.5;  %% generate input bits with equal probabilities
        x = 2 * s - 1; %% BPSK Modulation
        w = 1/sqrt(2) * (randn(n_Tx,1) + 1i * randn(n_Tx,1));  %% AGWN
        h = 1/sqrt(2) * (randn(n_Tx,n_Rx) + 1i * randn(n_Tx,n_Rx));  %% Rayleigh Channel
        y = h'*x + 10^(-Eb_No_dB(ii)/20) * w;  %% transmitted signal through the channel
        h_hat = squeeze(sum(h, 2));
        % Receiver
        y_out = y./h_hat;

        % hard decision decoding
        y_r = real(y_out)>0;
        n_Error(ii) = size(find((s - y_r), 1));

    end

end
Sim_BER = n_Error/N;
Eb_No_Lin = 10.^(Eb_No_dB/10);
BER_Ray_Theory_Rx1 = 0.5 .* (1 - sqrt(Eb_No_Lin./(1 + Eb_No_Lin)));  %% BER due to TX1
p = 1/2 - 1/2*(1+1./Eb_No_Lin).^(-1/2);
BER_Ray_Theory_Rx2 = p.^2.*(1+2*(1-p)); 
semilogy(Eb_No_dB, Sim_BER, 'k*-', 'LineWidth', 2);
hold on;
semilogy(Eb_No_dB, BER_Ray_Theory_Rx1, 'ms-', 'LineWidth', 2);
semilogy(Eb_No_dB, BER_Ray_Theory_Rx2, 'R>-', 'LineWidth', 2);
axis([-1 20 10^-7 1]);
grid on;
xlabel('Eb-No-dB', 'FontSize', 12); ylabel('BER', 'FontSize', 12);
legend('SimulatioN-BER (Rx=Tx=2 WITH ZF)', 'Theory-BER (Tx=Rx=1)', 'Theory-BER(Tx2=1,Rx=2, MRC');
title('BER FOR BPSK MODULATION WITH 2X2 MIMO & ZERO-FORCING EQUALIZER');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the full error message you are shown the location of the error:

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in SOcode (line 22)
        n_Error(ii) = size(find((s - y_r), 1));
```

Here you've restricted [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to find the *first* index where `(s - y_r) ~= 0`, which is always going to return either a scalar or an empty array. Per the documentation for [`size`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html), the output is always going to be a row vector, even for scalars, so the number of elements is always going to be `>= 2`. `n_Error(ii)` is a scalar index, so it's impossible to fit more than one element, causing the above error.

To resolve this issue, use something like [`numel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) or [`length`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/length.html) instead of `size`.

Comment: As you point out, `find(x, 1)` will only ever return a scalar or `[]`. The OP probably wants `numel(find(s-y_r)))` which is equivalent to `nnz((s - y_r)~=0)`, where `nnz` is the number of non-zero elements (i.e. a match). This will be quicker and more explicit than using `numel(find(...))`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer has perfectly solved the problem.